# How can I use TensorFlow without CUDA on Linux?

Tags: python, linux, cuda, tensorflow

I have two computers without CUDA: one runs on Microsoft Windows, the other one runs on Linux (Ubuntu 14.04 64bit / Linux 3.13.0-100-generic))

I can use TensorFlow without CUDA on Microsoft Windows without any issue: TensorFlow uses the CPU. However, if on the Linux machine I run  in python  `import tensorflow as tf`, then TensorFlow fails to get imported due to CUDA being not installed:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/__init__.py", line 24, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import *
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 72, in <module>
    raise ImportError(msg)
ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/__init__.py", line 61, in <module>
    from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 28, in <module>
    _pywrap_tensorflow = swig_import_helper()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 24, in swig_import_helper
    _mod = imp.load_module('_pywrap_tensorflow', fp, pathname, description)
ImportError: libcudart.so.8.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory


Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.

See https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/g3doc/get_started/os_setup.md#import_error

for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
above this error message when asking for help.
```

How can I use TensorFlow without CUDA on Linux?

I use `tensorflow-gpu==1.0.0`.

---

I'm aware of the parameter `device_count` in  `tensorflow.ConfigProto`, which allows to disable the GPU, e.g.:

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.constant(1, name = 'a')
b = tf.constant(3, name = 'b')
c = tf.constant(9, name = 'c')
d = tf.add(a, b, name='d')
e = tf.add(d, c, name='e')

config = tf.ConfigProto(device_count={'CPU': 1, 'GPU': 0})
sess = tf.Session(config=config)
print(sess.run([d, e]))
```

but it doesn't help since  `import tensorflow as tf` is the issue.

I also know how to install CUDA 8:

```
# Install Nvidia drivers, CUDA and CUDA toolkit, following some instructions from http://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-installation-guide-linux/index.html
wget https://developer.nvidia.com/compute/cuda/8.0/Prod2/local_installers/cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb
sudo dpkg -i cuda-repo-ubuntu1404-8-0-local-ga2_8.0.61-1_amd64-deb
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install cuda
```

but would prefer to avoid it on these two machines.

Comment: Using `tensorflow-gpu` means you must have CUDA drivers installed, even if the machine has no GPUs. Without gpu drivers you must use a version that's compiled to be CPU-only

Comment: in our fleet, we install GPU drivers on both GPU and non-GPU machines to be able to use same TF binary

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov Thanks, I wasn't aware `tensorflow-gpu` required CUDA (I thought it would allow to optionally use GPU). That explains. Good to know one can install the GPU drivers on non-GPU machines, that should indeed facilitate deployments.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov if you wanted to summarize your comments in an answer, I'm sure it would be useful for others, and I would upvote.

Comment: @YaroslavBulatov and I'd accept the answer :) I'm leaving the question even though it is basic in case someone else (e.g. folks migrating from Theano) wonders the same.

Comment: According to https://groups.google.com/a/tensorflow.org/forum/#!topic/build/J4rCwzLYs_Q, "the current `tensorflow-gpu` package (the nightly version of which now also runs on machines without GPUs, or without CUDA driver installed)".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you build the binary with `--config=cuda` (as was done for `tensorflow-gpu`) then your machine must have GPU drivers. You can install GPU drivers on the machine even if the machine doesn't have GPU which is the common practical solution.

What happens is that `--config=cuda` sets [GOOGLE_CUDA](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/search?utf8=%E2%9C%93&q=GOOGLE_CUDA&type=Code) macro in the code which changes behavior during runtime. In particular it causes dso_loader to run which you can see by following line printed

```
2017-02-16 17:15:08: I tensorflow/stream_executor/dso_loader.cc:125] successfully opened CUDA library libcurand.8.0.dylib locally
```

A popular approach at Google is to deploy a "fat" binary -- ie binary that bundles drivers and client code for all possible hardware accelerators because that simplifies testing and deployment.

In open-source release, drivers and client code are separate, but this pattern remains -- the GPU-capable binary is expecting to have GPU drivers available.