# Is it possible to run tensorflow-gpu on a computer without a GPU or CUDA?

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have two Windows computers, one with and one without a GPU.

I would like to deploy the same python script on both (TensorFlow 1.8 Object Detection), without changing the packaged version of TensorFlow. In other words, I want to run tensorflow-gpu on a CPU.

In the event where my script cannot detect `nvcuda.dll`, I've tried using a Session config to disable the GPU, like so:

```
config = tf.ConfigProto(
    device_count = {'GPU': 0}
)
```

and:

```
with tf.Session(graph=detection_graph, config=config) as sess:
```

However, this is not sufficient, as TensorFlow still returns the error:

```
ImportError: Could not find 'nvcuda.dll'. TensorFlow requires that this DLL be installed in a directory that is named in your %PATH% environment variable.
Typically it is installed in 'C:\Windows\System32'. If it is not present, ensure that you have a CUDA-capable GPU with the correct driver installed.
```

Is there any way to disable checking for a GPU/CUDA entirely and default to CPU?

**EDIT:** I have read the year-old answer regarding tensorflow-gpu==1.0 on Linux [posted here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42287754/9291214), which suggests this is impossible. I'm interested to know if this is still how tensorflow-gpu is compiled, 9 versions later.

Comment: As far as I am aware, that answer is still accurate.  Is there a reason you cannot install cuda on both machines?

Comment: There is no pressing technical reason, apart from the added complexity of installing otherwise non-functional drivers. Does a tensorflow-gpu installation that detects CUDA but not a GPU automatically default to CPU?

Comment: I haven't used the Python API in a while, but if you want to use GPU's I believe you need both CUDA and cudNN installed on the machine.  If you want to use a CPU with tensorflow-gpu, I believe it just requires CUDA, and will then default to a CPU

Comment: My personal recommendation would be to look into containerizing the solution, that removes the need to handle any prerequisites at all on either machine.  I would start by looking into nvidia-docker